# Finding 2 values if available in a list in a Django Template

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, list, if-statement

I have the following list called `` :`[(2, 'Flat Bench'), (1, 'Flat Bench'), (3, 'Flat Bench')]`

I am trying to find if the `b.order` which is the first number and `e.name` which is the 2nd string is available from a django template. In my trial I made sure that `b.order` is equal to 2 and `e.name` is 'Flat Bench'.

Here is the django template:

```
  {% if b.order and e.name in all_logs %}
  available
  {% else%}
  not available
  {% endif %}
```

In my case there is no error, it is just always showing not available even if it is available.

I am not sure what change I should be doing to get this code to work.

Comment: Based on the called list your if statement should be {% if (b.order, e.name) in all_logs %}

Comment: @Abdullah I tried this one also before and again now to make sure but it got me this error `django.template.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: Could not parse the remainder: '(b.order,' from '(b.order,'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I would suggest to create custom tags as explained here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/custom-template-tags/

Your custom function should look as follows:

my_custom_tags.py

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()


@register.simple_tag
def tuple_check(items, key, value):
    return (key, value) in items
```

Your template should have the following:

```
{% load my_custom_tags %}
...
some codes here
...

{% tuple_check your_list b.order e.name as item_check_result %}

{% if item_check_result %}
Available
{% else %}
Not Available
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
{% if b.order in all_logs and e.name in all_logs %}
  available
  {% else%}
  not available
{% endif %}
```

This way, it checks each if each item is in the list separately. If they both are, (no matter if index differs) it will show available.

Comment: I tried the above code before and tried it again now but it is still showing not available in all cases